# error with indentation using JADE

Tags: angularjs, pug, indentation

I am trying to create a simple jade template (I am relatively new to jade) and I keep getting an error with this piece of code:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    div(ng-controller="AppCtrl")
    h1 Angulair
        ul(ng-repeat="airport in airports") 
            li airport.code
            li airport.city
            li airport.name
```

I am using angular with it too, but the error I am getting is that the indentation is incorrect. Before, I had the code like this:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    div(ng-controller="AppCtrl")
        h1 Angulair
             ul(ng-repeat="airport in airports") 
                li airport.code
                li airport.city
                li airport.name
```

Where the second h1 tag was indented again, but that was still giving me an error. The exact error looks like this:

500 Error: /Users/AllanAraujo/Desktop/testapp 5/views/index.jade:7
 5| div(ng-controller="AppCtrl")
 6| h1 Angulair
 > 7| ul(ng-repeat="airport in airports") 
 8| li airport.code
 9| li airport.city
 10| li airport.name
Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both

Any help is great, thank you.

Comment: If answers to this post helped you, please accept by hittin the green checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    div(ng-controller="AppCtrl")
        h1 Angulair
        ul(ng-repeat="airport in airports") 
            li airport.code
            li airport.city
            li airport.name
```

The way you had it the `ul` would have been  a child of the `h1`, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

All of your indentations have 4 spaces. The line with `ul` has an extra space.

It's easy to see in SublimeText, with its tab lines.

[image: Extra space in tab.]